# WordPress "wp-admin" redirecting to a user account login

Tags: login

I’m getting a very strange error. When I try to log in to the back-end of WordPress at the address mysite.com/wp-admin, to access the back-end, I am automatically being redirected to mysite.com/login.php... as if I were trying to log into an account as a regular user or a customer.

I’m a novice with WordPress, and I can’t seem to figure this out. Please help.

I have a website which allows some of the users to post available jobs around the block and others apply through it.

Thank You

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with some [basic debugging](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/debug/info) information?

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you have a plugin installed that is blocking access to the wp-admin page and redirecting it to your front-end login page. There may be a way to bypass it depending on the plugin.

One thing you can try to do is just logging in using your regular admin password on the front-end customer login page. The plugin may be using the built in Wordpress users functionality to implement front end user accounts and it would automatically allow you to access wp-admin once you're logged into an admin account.

If that doesn't work - try finding out what plugin you're using to block the login access (what plugin are you using to implement the front end logins?) - then look up a way to bypass it.

Comment: For anyone who has woocommerce, you need to just add the view_admin_dashboard as a custom capability